# Speculation. Will this "turning-co2-into-O2" zeppelin work in Venus?

Tags: venus, terraforming, chemistry

Background: Me and a friend are trying to "colonize" Mars and Venus. He has Mars, and I have to "colonize" Venus. So, my intention was to do a slow terraform by creating zeppelins that convert CO2 into O2 (and biomass as a byproduct) This is the prototype of the zeppelin, white patches are the inside of the prototype:
[image: Zeppelin]

Questions:

1. Will be necessary a filter for the H2SO4? (the sulphuric clouds of venus)
2. Can graphene solar panels (even on the bottom for the albedo) be enough to power the fans inside/outside the zeppelin? And, do they exist/can exist?
3. Materials or paint for sulphuric acid? I know they exist, but I couldn't find if they decay or the materials get rusty and need to get replaced, or if they deteriorate if they go to space.
4. Could there be a ventilation system to take the CO2 from the top to the bottom, and then carrying only the O2 outside the zeppelin (without CO2 entering inside?

And, finally, a really space question: Would this be easy to deliver to Venus? Will it be expensive to build?

By the way, don't mind the "micro-bacterial algae" I'm working on it at the moment.

Comment: This asks a lot of things at once. It would be necessary to see a much more specific design to answer some parts, but the design isn't based on engineering knowledge so that would seem undoable. Please bear in mind that this site is for brief, specific answers and avoids speculation. Ask about materials for sulphuric acid on [chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Scratch the fans on the outside. You don't need to maneuver.